# Spring data query where column is null

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have entities (getters/setters and various details omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
class Customer{
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer")
    Collection<Coupon> coupons;
}

@Entity
class Coupon{
    ...
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date usedOn;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    Customer customer;
}
```

I wish retrieve all Coupons for a given Customer having null usedOn.
I,'ve unsuccessfully defined a method in the CouponRepository as described in [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)

```
@Repository
public interface CouponRepository extends CrudRepository<Coupon, Long> {
     Collection<Coupon> findByCustomerAndUsedOnIsNull(Customer);
}
```

but this leads on a compiler error `Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

My fault, the correct definition is

```
@Repository
public interface CouponRepository extends CrudRepository<Coupon, Long> {
     Collection<Coupon> findByCustomerAndUsedOnIsNull(Customer customer);
}
```

I simply missed the parameter name :-(

Comment: Wow lol At least this post helped me find how to use "IsNull"

Answer (score 33):

You can use **IsNull** to check null columns in JPA query.

For example for any ***columnA*** you can write query like query like

```
findByColumnAIsNull
```

In this case you can write queries like

```
@Repository
public interface CouponRepository extends CrudRepository<Coupon, Long> {
 Collection<Coupon> findByCustomerAndUsedOnIsNull(Customer customer);
 List<Coupon> findByUsedOnIsNull();
}
```

Also you can check how this queries will be 
[image]
Refer this Spring Data JPA Query creation this will help you lot to understand and create different type of JPA query variation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Nikunj Undhad, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Shree, I updated answer with full description do you think now its understandable by everyone who face this problem.

Answer (score 14):

Try changing your method to this (assuming `Customer.id` is a long):

`Collection<Coupon> findByCustomer_IdAndUsedOnIsNull(Long customerId);`

then use like this:

`repo.findByCustomer_IdAndUsedOnIsNull(customer.getId());`